# ¿Se puede usar la Api Google Vision para detectar codigos QR en una imagen?

Tags: google-api

he estado investigando como detectar objetos en una imagen en especial codigos QR que pueden estar en una imagen y me tope con la [api de google](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer?hl=es-419) que detecta objetos en imagenes, pero no se si es capaz de detectarme los codigos QR de alguna imagen, es posible esto?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], al momento esta pregunta es muy general, mas allá de un si o un no veo difícil que te puedan responder algo mas. ¿Has buscado su documentación y checado si dice algo al respecto?

Comment: fijate si algún port / fork te sirve, hay varias librerias basadas en zxing https://github.com/zxing/zxing#zxing-based-third-party-open-source-projects